# Fill DataGrid from WPF TextBox in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I have a script that I am trying to turn into a GUI.

There is a `DataGrid` in place with 2 columns and I have two `TextBox`es that I would like to be able to type something into that populates the `DataGrid`.

`box1` populates the first column, `box2` populates the second column.

I need help with the `KeyDown` and the population parts.

```
#LoadForm
./LoadDialog.ps1 -XamlPath 'C:\Forms\ReNamer.xaml'

#EVENT Handler
$NewName 

#Add old name manually
#################################PLEASE HELP HERE
$OldName.Add_KeyDown {
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq 'Enter') {
        $AddOldName.Invoke()
        #Suppress sound from unexpected use of enter on keyPress/keyUp
        $_.SuppressKeyPress = $true
    }
}
$AddOldName.Add_Click({ AddOldName })

##$renameBtn.Add_Click({ $Form.Close() })

$Import.Add_Click({ GetCompList })

#Launch the window
$xamGUI.ShowDialog() | Out-Null

#Csv import button
Function GetCompList {
    ##File location
    $csvfile = Import-Csv "C:\Sysinternals\rename.csv" |
        Select-Object @{ n = "OldName"; e = { $_.OldName } }, @{ n = "NewName"; e = { $_.NewName } }

    $csvfile | ForEach-Object { $dataGrid.AddChild($_) }
}

#Run Button
Function RenameComputers {
    Write-Host "Renaming computer from: $o to: $n"
    netdom renamecomputer $o /newName:$n /uD:sdirc\clarkj8 /passwordD:$p /force /reboot
}

#NewName txtbox

#OldName txtBox
##############################################PLEASE help here
Function AddOldName {
    $row = New-Object PSObject
    Add-Member -InputObject $row -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "OldName" -Value $OldName.Text
}
```

Comment: Hi, why roll my edit back? (I cleaned up and fixed your code)

Comment: I did not mean too. New to these forums and how it all works. i went in to edit out a username. and did it accidentally

Comment: OK, no problem. I've tried to fix things. Please take a look at the code and amend it if you wanted to change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function AddOldName {

    $row = New-Object PSObject

    Add-Member -InputObject $row -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "OldName" -Value $OldName.Text

    Add-Member -InputObject $row -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "NewName" -Value $NewName.Text

    $dataGrid.AddChild($row)

}
```

(assuming your new name field is called `$newName`)

And then in that function you could also do:

```
netdom renamecomputer $OldName.text /newName:$NewName.text /uD:sdirc\clarkj8 /passwordD:$p /force /reboot
```

And on your computer list import function you could also do:

```
$csvfile | % { netdom renamecomputer $_.OldName /newName:$_.NewName /uD:sdirc\clarkj8 /passwordD:$p /force /reboot }
```

I haven't tried `KeyDown`s in Powershell before though.

Comment: Thank you. That did get the function above working. Now i just need to get the KeyDown part correct.

Comment: This has worked on and off. Mostly it seems to just create a blank row.           Function AddName{ 
    $row = New-Object PSObject 
    Add-Member -InputObject $row -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Old Computer Name" -Value $OldName 
    Add-Member -InputObject $row -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "New Computer Name" -Value $NewName 
    $DataGrid.AddChild($row)
}

Comment: Did you set the bindings to be "Old Computer Name" and "New Computer Name" in the xaml?